# Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php on line 22

Tags: php, iis, dcom, com, email-server

There is an IIS 7 webserver and PHP 5.3

I have set com.allow_dcom = true on php.ini file and restarted the webserver.

I need to use hmailserver by:

```
$obBaseApp = new COM("hMailServer.Application");
```

It says:

> Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php on
>   line 22

Comment: Exact Version of PHP is 5.3.16

Answer (score 3):

> The php 5.4.5 build from windows.php.net ships the com/dotnet module
>   as extension dll. If that's the case with your version of php too you
>   can enable the module via
>
> ```
> extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
> ```
>
> in your php.ini

Quotation from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002924/1274378

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows 8 and Apache server and `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` not worked for you then:

copy `php_com_dotnet.dll` file to `c:/windows/system32` and write to `php.ini` file.

```
extension = c:/windows/system32/php_com_dotnet.dll
```

I'm using Windows 8 and Apache server for windows. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this problem:

open your php.ini from php example : c:/xampp/php/php.ini

add ***extension=php_com_dotnet.dll*** to the extensions in php.ini file

if you are using this tool to control a microsoft office document make sure that microsoft office is installed in your windows server and don't forget that the **COM** tools works only on windows servers like microsoft windows server 2012

restart your server

run your code